# Node.js script to connect to MySQL database through socket.io

Tags: mysql, node.js, socket.io, appcelerator-mobile, titanium-mobile

I have developed a Node.js script to connect to a MySQL database using socket.io. However, when I do try and connect to the server using my Titanium client application, it just passes over the connection method which I have created; there are no error messages or messages of any kind, and the socket just closes without calling the script. Does anybody understand what my problem might be. For the reference, my code is:

```
    var app = require('net')
      , fs = require('fs')
      , Client = require('mysql').Client
      , client = new Client();  

    client.user = 'user';
    client.password = 'password'; // Obviously this is not my real password

    var sockets_list = [];

    var server = app.createServer(function (socket) {
      sockets_list.push(socket);
      socket.write("Hello Client\r\n");

      socket.on('data', function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        for (var i = 0; i < sockets_list.length; i++) {
            sockets_list[i].write(data);
        }


      });

      client.connect(function(err, results) {
        if (err) {
            console.log("ERROR: " + err.message);
            socket.write("NO!\r\n");
            throw err;
        }
        console.log("connected.");
        socket.write("Got through here\r\n");
        clientConnected(client);
      });

      socket.on('end', function() {
        var i = sockets_list.indexOf(socket);
        sockets_list.splice(i, 1);
      });


    });



    server.listen(8080);

    clientConnected = function(client)
    {
        client.query('USE db', function(err, results) {
            if (err) {
                console.log("ERROR: " + err.message);
                throw err;
            }
        });
    };
```

If somebody could tell me where I am going wrong with this code, it would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Regards

The Gyro Captain

---

As I mentioned previously, I have continued to work on this script using node-mysql-libmysqlclient, but I have been encountering some difficulty with actually connecting to the server. My connection script is attached here:

```
exports.CallStoredProcedureSync = function (test) {
test.expect(12);

var conn;
var result;
var row;
var rows;
var host = "localhost";
var user = "test";
var password = **********;
var database = *******;

var sockets_list = [];
conn = mysql.createConnectionSync();
conn.connectSync(host, user, password, database, 0, 0, conn.CLIENT_MULTI_RESULTS);

if (!conn.connectedSync()) 
{   
sys.puts("Connection error " + conn.connectErrno + ": " + conn.connectError);
socket.write("Connection error " + conn.connectErrno + ": " + conn.connectError);
process.exit(1);
}
// More code here
}
```

However, I can't actually access any of the Code defined after the connection. If somebody could tell me where I am going wrong, I would greatly appreciate it. For the record, I am using the test code for node-mysql-libmysqlclient here: https://github.com/Sannis/node-mysql-libmysqlclient/blob/master/tests/complex/test-call-stored-procedure.js. Thanks.

Regards

The Gyro Captain

Comment: Hope this will help http://nodejs.org/

Comment: Thanks. I have already had a look at Node.js's website and I have decided to stop using the node-mysql package in favour of the node-mysql-libmysqlclient package.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my attempt at your problem using [node-mysqlclient](https://github.com/Sannis/node-mysql-libmysqlclient), it connects to the db and pulls back everything in a selected table, then it writes out a dummy string to the socket.  You may also want to look at [socket.io](http://socket.io/)... you mentioned it in your question but it wasn't used in this app.

```
var app = require('net')
  , mysql = require('mysql-libmysqlclient')
  , conn = mysql.createConnectionSync();


conn.connectSync('localhost', 'user', 'password', 'database');
conn.setCharsetSync('utf8');

var sockets_list = [];

var server = app.createServer(function (socket) {
  sockets_list.push(socket);
  socket.write("Hello Client\r\n");

  socket.on('data', function(data) {
    console.log(data);
    for (var i = 0; i < sockets_list.length; i++) {
      sockets_list[i].write(data);
    }
  });

  clientConnected = function() {
    conn.query('SELECT * FROM table', function(err, results) {
      if (err)
        throw err;
      else {
        results.fetchAll(function (err, rows) {
        if (err)
          throw err;
        // print out database info
        console.log(rows);
        socket.write('socket writes here');
      });
      }
    });
  };

  clientConnected();

  socket.on('end', function() {
    var i = sockets_list.indexOf(socket);
      sockets_list.splice(i, 1);
  });
});

server.listen(8080);
```

~